# Reading hexascii in Python 2.7 vs Python 3.5x

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, encoding

I have a function built that reads in hex-ascii encoded data, I built that in Python 2.7.  I am changing my code over to run on 3.x and hit an unforeseen issue.  The function worked flawlessly under 2.7.  Here is what I have:

```
# works with 2.7
data = open('hexascii_file.dat', 'rU').read()
```

When I run that under 3.x I get a UnicodeError:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 500594: invalid start byte
```

I thought the default codec under Python 2.7 was ascii, so I tried the following under 3.x:

```
data = open('hexascii_file.dat', 'rU', encoding='ascii')
```

This did not work (same error as above, but specifying 'ascii' instead of 'utf-8'.  However, when I use the latin-1 codec all works well.

```
data = open('hexascii_file.dat', 'rU', encoding='latin-1')
```

I guess I am looking for a quick sanity check here to ensure I have made the proper change to the script.  Does this change make sense?

Comment: What does "hex-ascii encoded" mean?

Comment: hex-encoding written as ascii charachters.  I think the data are stored as such for compressions.  For example, '00040' is representative of 64 ( int('00040',16)), while '0x85' is 133.